# Java Heap Size - 32/64bit issue?

Tags: java, heap-memory, jena

I'm trying to run a Jena GeoSparql instance and I'm hitting memory limits. I don't know how much memory, ultimately, it'll need.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I get that `-Xmx10536m`increases the heap size, but I still need more than it'll let me allocate.

```
java -jar -Xmx10536m jena-fuseki-geosparql-3.17.0.jar --convert_geo --tdb spatialdb2
```

I believe I have the latest Java installed.

> java -version java version
> "1.8.0_131" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11) Java
> HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Does "mixed mode" mean it's not running in purely 64-bit mode, hence the limitation?

Comment: **It's not 64-bit at all.** There are no 'modes' for bitness; a 32-bit JVM runs in 32-bit always and entirely, a 64-bit JVM runs in 64-bit always and entirely. If the version message doesn't say 64-bit, it's not 64-bit at all ever, it's 32-bit always and only. And 32-bit can never address more than 4G max, usually less.

Comment: The OP reported it now works.

BTW 1.8.0 is not the latest java. build 291 exists and java itself is at 11 (LTS)